# model.evaluate() and model.predict () return very different results

Tags: python, keras, evaluate

This is my model's architecture:

```
def generate_network_2 (lr = 3e-3, drop = 0.4):
  
  
  #filters = 64
  model = keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size = 5, strides = 2, activation = 'relu', padding = "same",
                                input_shape = (312, 312, 3)))
  model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding = "same"))
  model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization())
  
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size = 3, activation="relu", padding = "same"))         
  model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size = 3, activation="relu", padding = "same"))          
  model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding = "same"))
  model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization())
  
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size = 3, activation="relu", padding = "same"))          
  model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(256,  kernel_size = 3, activation="relu", padding = "same"))        
  model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding = "same"))
  model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization())
 
  model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
  model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64,  activation = "relu"))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(drop))
  model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16,activation = "relu"))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(drop))
  model.add(keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = "softmax"))

  optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr)
  

  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
                
  return model
```

When I run model.evaluate on the validation dataset, I get a 69% accuracy. However, when I manually calculate the accuracy and the confusion matrix using model.predict, I got ~ 31%

```
model.evaluate(valid_gen)
```

4/4 [==============================] - 2s 506ms/step - loss: 0.7732 - accuracy: 0.6917
[0.773181676864624, 0.6916666626930237]

```
def print_cm(cm, labels):
    """pretty print for confusion matrixes"""
    columnwidth = max([len(x) for x in labels])
    # Print header
    print(" " * columnwidth, end="\t")
    for label in labels:
        print("%{0}s".format(columnwidth) % label, end="\t")
    print()
    # Print rows
    for i, label1 in enumerate(labels):
        print("%{0}s".format(columnwidth) % label1, end="\t")
        for j in range(len(labels)):
            print("%{0}d".format(columnwidth) % cm[i, j], end="\t")
        print()

pred = np.argmax(model.predict(valid_data), axis=-1)
actual = valid_data.classes
cm = confusion_matrix(actual,pred)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print_cm(cm, ["0", "1", "2"])
```

Confusion Matrix
0   1   2
0   9   12  15
1   8   16  14
2   12  19  15

```
                 Classification Report
           precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.31      0.25      0.28        36
       1       0.34      0.42      0.38        38
       2       0.34      0.33      0.33        46

accuracy                           0.33       120
```

macro avg       0.33      0.33      0.33       120
weighted avg       0.33      0.33      0.33       12

Comment: Are you using imagedatagenerator? If you do, can you add your generator code details?

Comment: Yes. I  only have feature wise_std_normalization = True in the ImageDataGenerator. I also use  data_generator.fit(trainX) to calculate the statistics.

Comment: Also which parameters do you use for flow function? Sorry I forgot to also ask flow function.

Comment: I use flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = data, x_col = 'filename', y_col = 'int_label',target_size = (312, 312), class_mode = 'categorical', shuffle = True, subset = 'training')

Comment: Since you are predicting valid_data, try to set shuffle = False for valid_data.

Comment: I've already tried that but it did not solve the problem. I also tried evaluating on the training set but still model.evaluate() gave me 85% and model.predict() 33%. not sure what the problem is

Comment: Hmm, try setting batch size = 1 for valid data, also shuffle = False, then pred =(model.predict(valid_data, steps = 3)).argmax(axis = 1)

Comment: Oh I think I got it. The results in both methods are now the same. But was this due to setting shuffle = True or the batch_size because I tried switching off shuffle but it did not solve the problem but worsened the validation accuracy.

Comment: When you shuffle, valid_data.classes will be messed up. Also we want to make 1 prediction at a time so we divide sample size to batch size, which is giving steps. If your question is truly solved, I will add this as an answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help!